# GCC symbol lookup error

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, symbols, undefined-symbol

I try to launch my executable but i got this error:

> .dudac/stage/monkey/lib/hello.duda: undefined symbol: DDS_sequence_BoardGlobalParameters_BoardGPSoftState__alloc

Whereas link and compile work fine

Here is my makefile:

```
# ====================================
# Date      : Tue 21, Feb 2017 at 10:15


NAME    = hello
CC      = /opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/x86_64-wrlinuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -DDEBUG -L/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/RTS/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/lib -ldcpssac -ldcpsisocpp2
#-g -Wall -DDEBUG -fPIC

LDFLAGS =
DEFS    =
INCDIR  =  -I/home/T0181049/.dudac/stage/monkey//include/ -I/home/T0181049/.dudac/stage/monkey//src/include -I/home/T0181049/.dudac/stage/monkey//plugins/duda/src -I/home/T0181049/.dudac/stage/monkey//plugins/duda/ -I/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/HDE/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/include -I/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/HDE/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/include/dcps/C/SAC -I/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/HDE/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/include/sys -I/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSplice/6.7.1p1/HDE/x86_64.linux/include -I/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSplice/6.7.1p1/HDE/x86_64.linux/include/sys -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++ -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/4.9.1 -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/arm-windriverv7atneon-linux-gnueabi -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/c++/4.9.1/backward -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/armv7at2-vfp-neon-wrs-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/dtc -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/x86_64-wrlinuxsdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/4.9.1/include -I/opt/windriver/wrlinux-small/7.0-xxxxx-3543dr/sysroots/x86_64-wrlinuxsdk-linux/usr/lib/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-wrs-linux-gnueabi/4.9.1/include-fixed


OBJECTS = main.o

_PATH     = $(patsubst /%, %, $(CURDIR))
_CC       = @/bin/echo -e "  [\033[33mCC\033[0m]   $@"; $(CC)
_DD       = @/bin/echo -e "  [\033[32mDD\033[0m]   $@"; $(CC)
_CC_QUIET = @/bin/echo -n; $(CC)

all: $(NAME).duda

$(NAME).duda: $(OBJECTS)
    $(_DD) $(CFLAGS) $(DEFS) -shared -o $@ $^ -lc $(LDFLAGS)

.c.o:
    $(_CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(DEFS) $(INCDIR) -fPIC $<
    $(_CC_QUIET) -MM -MP $(CFLAGS) $(DEFS) $(INCDIR) $*.c -o $*.d > /dev/null &2>&1

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.d *~ $(NAME).duda
```

How do i resolve that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

During linking you have specified libraries that are not in the standard path

Solutions

- link statically
- Use LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- Use LD_PRELOAD
- Use rpath

Comment: Which is the best solution ?
Link statically is just add -static to CFLAGS ?
How use LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD ?

Answer (score 0):

I try to use rpath just like this but got the same error:

> CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -DDEBUG -L/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/HDE/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/PrismTech/Vortex_v2/Device/VortexOpenSpliceRTE/6.7.1p2/HDE/armv7at2_vfp_neon.WRlinux7_gcc/lib -ldcpssac -ldcpsisocpp2